# How to use Symfony validation with json data

Tags: laravel, symfony

When I'm using Symfony v5.1 array of collection validation I got a strange response.

This is my code

```
   $constraint = new Assert\Collection([
        'email' => new Assert\Email(),
        'password' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 60]),
    ]);

    $violations = $validator->validate($request->request->all() , $constraint);

    foreach($violations as $violation)
    {
        $errors[] = [$violation->getPropertyPath() => $violation->getMessage()];
    }

    dd($errors);
```

and this is the result I got:

```
 array:5 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "[password]" => "This value is too short. It should have 60 characters or more."
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "[name]" => "This field was not expected."
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    "[phone_number]" => "This field was not expected."
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "[username]" => "This field was not expected."
  ]
  4 => array:1 [
    "[role_id]" => "This field was not expected."
  ]
]
```

so I'm wondering why the name of the input is swapping in array[] `[name]`
so is there is a wrong something I did?

And why Symfony is focused on entity `validation` and not on the `request` like Laravel framework?

Comment: have you taken a look at the validation component in symfony? The probably simplest way is to define validation on an object into which the json is going to be deserialized. But validation can also be done in more inconvenient ways, but the use case is a bit unknown right now, since you omitted ... well ... everything, really.

Comment: so how can implement what you found in the docs a separate way, I just want to pass the request object to another validation class to validate it then check on what return

Comment: have you tried something like this: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-rest2/validation-errors-response a class doesn't have to be an entity. but a class is a fine thing to define validation/constraints for, I don't know how laravel manages this, but symfony isn't primarily about api ...

Comment: or maybe you want to setup api-platform https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform

Comment: many thanks for help, but why should I do a class to validate it if I already have the request class with the data I want, so I want to send the `request->all()` to the validator class to validate it and this is what Laravel do

Comment: So, you're new to driving a car, and you have experience with a motorbike. I tell you how to operate the car door, and you tell me, "but I don't want to operate the car door, look, I don't need to operate any door with my motorbike." And although I understand, that your motorbike has no door, a car is something different and has different concepts. *takes a deep breath* I pointed you to 2 different approaches on how to handle this somewhat conveniently in symfony, but you want the laravel way. So my question now is: why do you use symfony when you want laravel?

Comment: here, third approach: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html

Comment: Man, I just don't like the way it uses it in the validation, I don't like the annotation as it coupling the model with the validation and I want a way to separate it. but also I want to validate the request coming from the user as it may have inputs not exist in the entity. so I am asking if there another way to handle the validation so if you don't know let the others help

Comment: @Jakumi if you read the DDD in PHP the used Symfony, and they implemented an abstraction way in the validation so I am searching for a simple way like that.
but anyway this is similar to what I want  
 https://gist.github.com/fesor/ba1b6a3aacb09a3e1cb82512235e84d2

Comment: You're free to use anything else than annotations, as documented at https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html - so, what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am trying to validate the request object not the entity itself, but thanks guys for help I am gonna implement something like this https://gist.github.com/fesor/ba1b6a3aacb09a3e1cb82512235e84d2 but in abstraction way

Comment: My question doesn't need any clarification you are the one who stuck in the framework and cannot get your mind out of it, @Jakumi about your car and motorbike example bro it so wrong if I'm using a framework I really don't like to stuck with it I can implement anything I want even if it is implemented In java or python not laravel itself, but your mind will not got this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a really package implementing what I need, it just works like as Laravel and validates the request so easy https://github.com/fesor/request-objects but it is not working on Symfony 5 so I upgraded it to be compatible with v5 wit some changes https://github.com/TheGeekyM/symfony-object-request-validation.

you just call the request in the controlled

```
namespace App\Controlles;

public function registerUserAction(RegisterUserRequest $request)
{
    // Do Stuff! The data is already validated!
}
```

and this is the request with the validations

```
use Fesor\RequestObject\RequestObject;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class RegisterUserRequest extends RequestObject
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return new Assert\Collection([
            'email' => new Assert\Email(['message' => 'Please fill in valid email']),
            'password' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 4, 'minMessage' => 'Password is to short']),
            'first_name' => new Assert\NotNull(['message' => 'Please provide your first name']),
            'last_name' => new Assert\NotNull(['message' => 'Please provide your last name'])
        ]);
    }
}
```

and that is it, enjoy